# Form navigation confusion in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring project

From the Controller AddForm.java a request is forwarded to a Form.jsp & onsubmit from there comes back to the same controller.

Code below

Form.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/view/include.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${action eq 'addowner'}"><c:set var="method" value="post"/></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><c:set var="method" value="put"/></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<h2><c:if test="${action eq 'addowner'}">New </c:if>Owner:</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="owner" method="${method}">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        First Name:
        <br/>
        <form:input path="firstName" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Last Name:
        <br/>
        <form:input path="lastName" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Address:
        <br/>
        <form:input path="address" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        City:
        <br/>
        <form:input path="city" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Telephone:
        <br/>
        <form:input path="telephone" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${action eq 'addowner'}">
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Add Owner"/></p>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Update Owner"/></p>
          </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form:form>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp" %>
```

AddFormController code

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/new")
@SessionAttributes(types = Owner.class)
public class AddOwnerForm {

    private final Clinic clinic;


    @Autowired
    public AddOwnerForm(Clinic clinic) {
        this.clinic = clinic;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(Model model) {
        Owner owner = new Owner();
        model.addAttribute(owner);
        model.addAttribute("action", "addowner");
        return "owners/form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Owner owner, SessionStatus status) {

            System.out.println(owner.toString());
            System.out.println("Inside AddOwner processSubmit method");
            this.clinic.storeOwner(owner);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/forms/owners/" + owner.getId();

    }

}
```

The problem is in the controller the setupForm method forwards the flow to the jsp but in jsp in the form tag nowhere action is given but on submit the flow comes back to the 
processSubmit method. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please also add your `@Controller` class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit a `form` without an `action` attribute, a browser typically makes the request to  the current URL. For example, if you had previously made a GET request to

```
www.yourhost.com/your-app/owners/new
```

Then submitting the `<form>` would send the request to the same URL.

---

I'm not sure if this is in the specification or just convention.